# Generic parameter convertible to usize in rust

Tags: generics, rust, type-conversion

I'm struggling with seemingly simple question.

I have a function in rust, which is wrapping the C-style array to a slice taking a pointer and size:

```
fn c_array_to_slice<'a,T>(ptr: *mut T, n: usize) -> &'a[T] {
    unsafe{ std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, n) }
}
```

The inconvenience is that the wrapped C API is inconsistent in how it stores array sizes. This could be i16, i32, u32 or usize. In order not to write `as usize` repeatedly in the client code I'd like to make `c_array_to_slice` to work with any integer type of 'n':

```
fn c_array_to_slice<'a,T,I>(ptr: *mut T, n: I) -> &'a[T] {
    unsafe{ std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, n as usize) }
}
```

Of course, this fails because I need some type bounds for converting to usize, but I can't figure out how to do this correctly. I tried this:

```
fn c_array_to_slice<'a,T,I: Into<usize>>(ptr: *mut T, n: I) -> &'a[T] {
    unsafe{ std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, n.into()) }
}
```

but it doesn't work when called with `n: i32`: "the trait bound 'usize: From' is not satisfied".

For now I'm out of ideas. How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, you can't convert all values of `i32` into an `usize` there are the `TryInto`/`TryFrom` traits for fallible conversions.